# How to implement accessibility on a custom listview control

Tags: .net, custom-controls, accessibility, vb.net-2010, coded-ui-tests

We use custom a custom listview control and listview items that do not implement accessibility so coded ui tests won't really work with them. I'm trying to implement accessibility and I'm just not really sure what I'm doing.

I've already gone through both of these (and I haven't been able to find any other examples):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.accessibleobject(v=vs.110).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/05/17/enabling-ui-testing-for-third-party-winforms-custom-controls-1.aspx

I've gotten to the point where listview items can be highlighted, clicked, and asserted on with Coded UI tests but I'm still having trouble with the playback selecting the correct item.

I think it's because of the Name property on my listviewitem's AccessibleObject:

```
Public Overrides Property Name As String
  Get
    Return p_itmOwner.SubItems(0).Text.ToString
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    p_itmOwner.SubItems(0).Text.SetValue = value
  End Set
End Property
```

I notice if there are multiple items in the listview where the 1st column is the same, it will just select the 1st one it finds. What is the correct way to make a ListItem accessible? I could probably append the text of all of the columns in the Name property, but that doesn't really seem like the right solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI stops searching after it finds the first control matching the search criteria.

You can try finding all the matching list items, then selecting the correct one.  Sorry it's in C#.

```
            UITestControlCollection matchingListItems = listItem.FindMatchingControls();
        ((WinListItem)matchingListItems[matchingItemIndex]).Select();
```

Comment: I read that it will keep searching on increasingly more specific criteria until it only finds 1 control. And if it goes through all of it's criteria and still has more than 1 then it will just return the first. Some how I need to add more criteria to the search but I don't know what to add. - And C# is cool. It's my preferred language, but at work I have to use VB.